# Send push notification with generic message

Tags: firebase, react-native, security, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase for sending notifications (FCM). 
I would like to send a message like
'You have a new secure message from...' but when a user opens a message I would like to display a proper message text (not generic one). I other words, in the notification bar, when the application is in the background I don't want to display a message body, but some generic text, so nobody can see message content.

I am using React Native.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. What have you tried so far?

Comment: No, I'm hoping that someone will provide me a solution.

Comment: I'm going to refer you to this: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)